# Помогите сделать так, что бы при заходе на сайт, он посылал сообщение в в беседу с ботом

Tags: php, веб-программирование, бот, telegram

Всем привет, пишу сайт не массового использования, требуется, что бы он при заходе на него, отправлял сообщение в беседу телеграм где есть этот бот по типу: "Пользователь перешёл по ссылке/на сайт". Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

````js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
         url: "page2.php", //куда отправляем данные
         type: "POST",
         cache:true,
         data: {}, //какие данные нужно получить с фронта
         success: function(data){   
           //что делаем на фронте по завершению
         }
       });
  });```
````